# Heroku Scheduler - When I try to run heroku run node, I get an error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to create some cron jobs via the Heroku scheduler plugin. I've tested my node script on my local machine and it works fine, however, when I commit and push to heroku, when I run `heroku run node check_work_orders.js`, I get this error:

```
Running node check_work_orders.js on ⬢ fms-sandbox... up, run.4992 (Free)
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/check_work_orders.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
```

For reference, I was following this [guide](http://www.modeo.co/blog/2015/1/8/heroku-scheduler-with-nodejs-tutorial).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you confirm that the exact command `node check_work_orders.js` works on your local machine. Also, is the file located in `/app` or in the project root? Is there anywhere in your project that might be referencing `/app/check_work_orders.js`? Do you have an app directory at all?

Answer (score 0):

Since my node file was location in my `app/check_work_orders.js` file, I needed to run `heroku run node app/check_work_orders.js`. This solved my problem. It was just a matter of running node in the correct directory on the Heroku server.